# Is it possible to drag a WPF element & handle drop in a WebBrowser with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, wpf, drag-and-drop, webbrowser-control

I have a WPF application with a WebBrowser displaying a standard web site.
I am able to call javascript functions with the method described [here](http://notions.okuda.ca/2009/06/11/calling-javascript-in-a-webbrowser-control-from-c/).

As of now, I can drag different types of WPF control into the WebBrowser, the drop event being handled in JavaScript. This is where I'm stuck.

When handling the drop event, I can't seem to find where is the control/object I'm dragging.
Is it even possible to convert C# object into a web-based object during drop?

Also, I tried handling drop in WPF and then call a function in the WebBrowser, but haven't found a way to handle drop without catching the click event too, which I don't want to.

Any help would be appreciate on the matter. Thanks!

Comment: Note sure what you're asking. Why do you want to darg WPF UI controls into WebBrowser, which has HTML/JavaScript inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be putting a string token in the drag info then in JavaScript retrieve this token then call a function from c# to get more info or doing what you need to do in response to the drop event.
c# code in starting the drag event event

```
   DataObject dataObject= new DataObject();
   dataObject.SetText("__myAppDragFlag__stringToken");
   DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, dataObject, DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

JavaScript drop handler

```
onDrop = function (eArg) {
var dropInfo=eArg.dataTransfer.getData("text");
//if dropInfo starts with '__myAppDragFlag__' this drop coming from your c# application then your token //is stringToken
//
}
```